# Typed DataSet + WCF. Service is receiving empty DataTable

Tags: asp.net, wcf, strongly-typed-dataset

I am using Typed DataSet and WCF Service. When I call ***Update*** method on WCF proxy method by adding new row in DataTable, I get DataTable with one row in Service method. This is working as expected.

However, when I call same ***Update*** method on WCF proxy by updating row in DataTable, I get empty DataTable in Service method. I checked proxy ***Update*** method and verified that before calling service method, DataTable has the modified row with row version as "Modified".

I am not able to find out why I am getting empty datatable in service method even if proxy client is sending DataTable with one row to Service. Interesting thing is Service method receives data when same ***Update*** method on WCF proxy method is called by adding new row.

Here is the way I am calling Service for updating row.

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
MyDataSet dataSet = client.GetContactByContactId(contactId);
MyDataSet.MyDataTable contactTable = MyDataSet.MyDataTable;
MyDataSet.ContactTableRow row = contactTable[0];
row.FirstName = "ABC";
return client.UpdateContact(contactTable);
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `UpdateContact` method ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer and the behavior is strange when the method returns a DataSet but the idea is bad: [Returning DataSets from WebServices is the Spawn of Satan and Represents All That Is Truly Evil in the World](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx)